# Show that $J_0(x) H(x)$ is also a Bessel Equation solution

Tags: generating-functions, distribution-theory

Recall that $J_0(x)$ is a solution of the Bessel equation. d^2y/dx^2 + (1/x)dy/dx + y(x) = 0 . Show that $J_0(x) H(x)$ is also a solution, where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Ummm.... what is $H(x)$?

Comment: $H(x)$ is heaviside distribution

Comment: On what domain?  $J_0 H$ isn't even differentiable on the entire domain of $J_0$, which obstructs it as a solution of Bessel's differential equation.  Perhaps you ask your question because there is a Laplace transform nearby, in which case the domain should *not* by the usual domain for Bessel's differential equation.

Comment: @EricTowers Well it is a solution of Bessel differential equation (not the same as the one given by OP)

Answer (score 0):

With $$y(x)=J_0(x) H(x)$$ 
(where $J_0$ is the smooth solution of $u''+\frac1x u'+u=0,u(0)=1$)

then $$y' = J_0' H+J_0H'= J_0' H + \delta$$ so that $\frac1x y' $ and hence $y''+\frac1xy'+y$ is not a distribution, you meant $$x^2 y'' + x y'+x^2 y=0$$ which is true in the sense of distributions